# Filezilla duplicate files at download

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've got a strange behavior with Filezilla and I hope someone is able to help me.

When I download large amounts of data via ftp, Filezilla is showing a prompt, that the file is already downloaded and it asked if it could overwrite it.

I always wonder at this point, because these files aren't the same, in most cases the "local" files ist smaller than the remote one.

Does anyone knows about this behavior?

Comment: Even if the files are different sizes, are the files the same name?

Comment: Yes they have the same name,  if not,  the program would not ask to overwrite

Comment: So, if the 2 files have the same name, why are you surprised it's asking you to overwrite it? Or did I miss the point of the question?

Comment: Or are you saying it's trying to download the same file multiple times from 1 source?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that FileZilla is taking the File Modification Date & Size of File on the server and is then comparing those attributes to the local file modification date & size of local file, and if there is a discrepency, it's prompting for confirmation.

This action is configurable, go under Edit -> Settings -> Transfer -> File Exists Action in FileZilla and choose the default action when this happens.

You can also submit a question to FileZilla directly in their forums, https://forum.filezilla-project.org/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me while trying to download a lot of files in queue, what I noticed is that sometimes FileZilla losses the connection and the file is just "created" in local but not really downloaded, so when FileZilla auto reconnects tries to download the failed file again and I end up getting that prompt to override the local file, which at this point is 0 bytes or less than the original because the first attempt failed miserably or just was incomplete.

Might be your problem too.